# Bash loop through all directories within a directory and if find any instance of string in each directories specific file do this

Tags: linux, bash, bash-scripting

I have a service that utilizes a unique user specified port for remote connections. I install multiple instances of this service and wrote a bash script to automate the installs. My installer has a built in check to prevent my own stupidity from trying to bind to ports already configured on previously installed instances. Previously I was using lsof like so...

`if [[ -z $(lsof -i :${service_port}) ]]; then`

Worked great until I realized sometimes I toggle down instances for periods of time and lsof only checks out ports currently in use.

So now I'm falling back to scraping the config files (cool? no more lsof dependency) of each instance which are small only about 5kb each quick to iterate through.

I tried this initially (each install is in it's own folder in installs_dir)...

```
while read -e -p "Port: " -i "" service_port; do
    for each_install in "${installs_dir}/"*
    do
        if grep -q Port=${service_port} "$each_install"/main.cfg; then
            printf "Port ${service_port} in use, try another port\n"
            break
        else
            # Write Config
        fi
    done
done
```

But it fires on each directory of course. Is there a way to make this write only once without making a while loop sandwich or possibly another command that doesn't have to search though all the files?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out...
Just had to use the -c flag to count matches in grep, -q to keep it clean and quiet, get outside of the for loop then and make sure there were no matches.

```
installs_dir="/my/dir"
while read -e -p "Service Port: " -i "" service_port; do
    s=0
    for each_install in "${installs_dir}/"*; do
        while grep -cq Port=${service_port} ${each_install}/main.cfg; do
            let "s++"
            break
        done
    done
    [ ${s} != 0 ] && printf "A server is already assigned to that port, try again.\n"
    [ ${s} == 0 ] && printf "Port assigned.\n" && break
done
```